# adding JUnit tests to an existing libgdx project

Tags: junit, libgdx

I'm trying to add JUnit tests to my existing libgdx project.

I've googled it and many results tell me to create a new folder in my projects where the tests are going to go.

I've created this folder but when i want to add this folder to my project in the source panel in project properties it turns out that project properties doesn't have a source panel.

[the project properties screen doesn't have a source panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsYCn.png)

I have also added this:

```
dependencies
{
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}
```

to the build.gradle file

this is my first time using libgdx and I'm really stuck on this

Comment: you want to add this to the build.gradle of the module you are adding tests to: sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = [ "test/" ] where "test/" should be folder where you put the tests classes